# Foundation4 Dropdown not closing when working differently with 2 CSS Files

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I have 2 CSS files (Compiled from SASS) that represent RTL and LTR design.
I also Have 2 separate HTML files, Each with their own reference to the CSS files:

RTL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ltr/app.css" />
```

LTR:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rtl/app.css" />
```

The dropdown is represented in the same way in both HTML files:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="some-dropdown" class="tiny content radius button dropdown">
```

When using the RTL CSS file, the dropdown works fine. But when using the LTR one, It remains open no matter where I click.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Dana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Seems like it was a Foundation Dropdown issue.

I just added the following code to the foundation.js file (instead of Foundation.rtl = true;):

```
if (document.documentElement.dir == 'rtl'){Foundation.rtl = true;}
else{Foundation.rtl = false;}
```